# Trigger azure kubernetes cronjob by azure function

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-functions, azure-aks

As per requirements we have docker container batch job running on azure kubernetes service which need to be trigger on arrival of files at azure blob storage location, please advise how this is possible or doable.
Or any other design alternative for example if we can use azure function to start batch job running on aks pod on the arrival of file in azure blob storage location. Is this approach possible

Answer (score 0):

Executing the workload in functions is not an option?

You could use EventGrid to collect the Azure File Events or send a message to Azure Service Bus/Storage Queue and from a pod listen to those events/messages. However this would require the pod to be running all the time

If you want true "event based processing" within Kubernetes your best option is [Keda](https://keda.sh/)

If your Kubernetes Management Plane is exposed to the internet or reachable from a VNet (you could connect azure functions to it (requires premium though)), you could execute kubectl commands. But I would recommend using one of the solutions above.

Keep in mind - the Azure functions blob trigger is not always 100% reliable. Use Messaging or Event Grid if possible.

Comment: Thanks Julian, in above solution as you said "and from pod listen to those events/messages..." But how to listen from pod , do we need to make code changes in batch job code to listen as batch job will be running on pod as docker container. OR is there is some inbuilt mechanism in pod which can point to service bus/queue and trigger the job on arrival of event/message, actually dev team  looking for a lift and shift solution without any batch code changes. If not then I can consider other option  if it support linux container and trigger based execution without batch code change.

Comment: Trigger based batch job are currently hosted on AWS Fargate and need to be migrated to azure service without any code change in java batch code

Comment: Yes, listening to those events would require code changes. If you don't need Kubernetes -  Azure Container Instance might be an option to be triggered from function. But again, listening and reacting natively would be the better option

Comment: Ok so you mean to say batch job running on Azure container instance can be trigger from azure function without needing batch job code change (convert to rest api)

Comment: It should be possible, but the same way you could also start the job on k8s if the K8s API is reachable. Better would be properly to port the code to azure functions or use keda

Comment: just one more question as req change and we need to schedule all batch job which will run at determined time and not trigger based ---- can be use azure batch service to schedule multiple (8) linux container batch job, does azure batch support linux container and how reliable and cost effective it is for production scenario versus AKS. Thanks

Comment: *linux docker container